Spontaneous emission and coherence
Assume I prepare a linear superposition $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|g \rangle+|e\rangle)$ between a ground and excited level for a large number of "atoms" (it can by any multilevel system, not necessarily an atom). We can assume that the lifetime of the excited level is long enough to allow us to create this superposition, but it is not infinite. Assume also that the excited state can decay to many other levels, beside $|g \rangle$, such that the probability of $|e \rangle$ decaying back to $|g \rangle$ is negligible for the purpose of this question. If I wait for a time much longer than the lifetime of the excited state (the ground state is stable), will I find half of my initially prepared "atoms" in $|g \rangle$ and the other spread among the other levels, or will all the "atoms" decay to the other levels?

You say there are lots of other levels, let's call these $e_i$ with time constants $\tau_i$ for the decay $e \to e_i$. Then the distribution of the atoms will depend on all the time constants $\tau_i$. If you wait long enough all the atoms will be in the ground state, and at shorter times they will be distributed over all the states. I don't see what this has to do with coherence unless you're assuming that photons emitted by some of the decays stimulate emission from other atoms.

What do you mean they will all be in the ground state? We assume here that after they decay to e_i they can't decay to g any more (if g->e and e->e_i are electric dipole allowed, g and e_i would have the same parity anyway).
